# Why are we getting "Authorization has been denied for this request." error?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Today we persist service url for every user when we first see them and then use service url to work with botbuilder sdk. Every now and then we are getting consistent errors from Microsoft with this error message:

> Authorization has been denied for this request.

This is the most recent occurrence:
[outage duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5hEc.png)

Could this happen because service url changes? If yes, should we constantly update service url on every message?

OR

Was there an outage? If yes, is there a status page we can see for these?

Comment: According to the error message it seems like the specified credentials do not have sufficient privileges to make this request. Please reverify if you have granted all the permissions. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-error-codes-and-error-handling#error-code-reference- Is there any console log/error you are getting? Could you please provide more details and repro steps, so that we can try from our end?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all we get from botbuilder sdk side any time we tried sending messages during that period of time. We didn't change permissions (or anything) and multiple of our clients (multiple MS Teams tenants) were affected for that period of time (you can see in the screenshot). Then the error just went away. Is there a status page that we can see?

Comment: Could you please share the service URL you used along with bot-id and timestamp during which it threw error?

Comment: This is the service url: https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/ from the most recent case. Timestamp is Feb 5, 2023 @ 08:21:58.809 EST. I would prefer a more private method of communication to share bot id and more if thats possible. Let me know where I can send it.

Comment: Separately, @Prasad-MSFT can you confirm whether service url can change after bot is installed?

Comment: You can send the required details to this alias `microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com`

Comment: Also, the service URLs are added based on user location. It is unlikely to change after bot is installed.